# how to get the values of all elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I have a bunch of input text fields that are in the same class `emps_l` with different values. I want to loop through the all elemets with that class and store the values in to an array!
Bellow is what I have done:

```
var emps = new Array();     
$.each(($(".emps_l").val()),function()({        
      emps.push($(".emps_l").val());        
});
console.log(emps);
```

I am totally lost, Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The majority of getter functions in jQuery only act on the first matched element (so returns a single value). Doing `$(".emps_l").val()` returns the value of the first element in the DOM that has the `emps_l` class, whereas doing `$(".emps_l").val(1);` would set the value of every element with the `emps_l` class to 1, then return that jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var emps = []; // This is considered slightly faster than new array

$('.emps_1').each(function(){
    emps.push(this.value);
});

console.log(emps);
```

Comment: Can just use `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()`. Saves you (unnecessarily) calling jQuery functions and is easier/faster to type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with `this.value` to create the array

```
var emps = $(".emps_l").map(function () {
    return this.value
}).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var emps = new Array();     
$.each(($(".emps_l:input").val()),function(index , item )({        
      emps.push($(item ).val());        
});
console.log(emps);
```